# Can IntelliJ show me the fully-qualified name of the parameter in a lambda?

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, fully-qualified-naming

In code with a lambda, such as this event listener in a Vaadin web app:

```
someWidget.addValueChangeListener( 
    event -> {
        …
    } 
);
```

…I want to know the exact type, the fully-qualified class name, of the parameter/argument `event`.

If I click on that word `event`, IntelliJ provides a light-bulb icon with a menu with a menu item offering to “Expand parameter types”. This results in `event` being changed to `AbstractField.ComponentValueChangeEvent < Checkbox, Boolean > event`:

```
someWidget.addValueChangeListener( 
    AbstractField.ComponentValueChangeEvent < Checkbox, Boolean > event -> {
        …
    } 
);
```

But I do not want to permanently change the source code. I just want some kind of tooltip or heads-up display to temporarily inform me of the full class name.

➥ Can IntelliJ be made to briefly display the fully-qualified class name of a lambda parameter?

Comment: Why can't you just hover over `addValueChangeListener` and press down the CTRL button?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nothing happens when hovering and pressing Control, or pressing Command (macOS).

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me.  IntelliJ should already give you verbose information on the method by hovering + CTRL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click in the parameter (such as your `event`)
2. Choose `View` > `Quick documentation`

[image]

I did have to click on the classname in the popup to get the full package though.